# WinSCP Script upload recursivelly all files matching a mask to the same folder

Tags: batch-file, ftp, winscp

I have a text file that I am calling from a batch file and it is not putting files recursively in the FTP site. The folder structure has subfolders which contain the files I want to copy among many other files. The put files only copy `C:\storage` only. After reading the documentation and trying other method is still not copying files recursively. (no folders to be copied with the RDF from subfolders)

The folder structure is random on different PC:

1. C:\storage\78286.S-92A.920024*.RDF
2. C:\Storage\folder1\78286.S-92A.920024*.RDF
3. C:\Storage\storage2\folder2\78286.S-92A.920024*.RDF

There are many RDF files, but the wildcard I am interested is the one you can see above. Basically I want to select all the *.RDF (as wildcard above from all the subfolders), but do not want the subfolders to be copied to the remote.

Please see code below.

```
option batch continue
option confirm off
option reconnecttime 900
open ftp://companyuser:!password@ftpsite.com/    
lcd "C:\storage"
put "C:\storage\78286.S-92A.920024*.RDF"   "/"
put "C:\storage\*\78286.S-92A.920024*.RDF" "/"
close 
exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not easy to do such custom processing with WinSCP scripting only.

But with [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) from a [PowerShell script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell), it's not difficult:

```sh
# Load WinSCP .NET assembly
Add-Type -Path "WinSCPnet.dll"

# Set up session options
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Ftp
    HostName = "ftp.example.com"
    UserName = "username"
    Password = "password"
}

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

Write-Host "Connecting ..."
$session.Open($sessionOptions)

$localPath = "C:\storage"
$remotePath = "/"
$wildcard = "78286.S-92A.920024*.RDF"
$localFiles = Get-ChildItem -Include $wildcard -Recurse -Path $localPath

foreach ($localFile in $localFiles)
{
    Write-Host "Uploading $($localFile.FullName)..."
    $session.PutFiles($localFile.FullName, $remotePath).Check()
}
```

Just extract a contents of [WinSCP .NET assembly package](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php) along with the script (say `flatupload.ps1`) and run it like:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File flatupload.ps1
```

---

The code is partly based on WinSCP example [Recursively move files in directory tree to/from SFTP/FTP server while preserving source directory structure](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_moves_files_keeping_directory_structure).

See also WinSCP forum question [Ignore folder structure when copying the files](https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=27829).

Answer (score 0):

Have look at doc on https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline

You can use command-line `winscp.com`

Your script seems good, it should need to be called with `winscp.com`

For ftp client on Linux, mput/mget(multiple file operation), command is available but it is not available with WinScp.

You can try some work around like first create folder using mkdir command (with winscp.com) and then use `synchronize` option with `winscp.exe` to update folder content.

Comment: I used winscp.com now and is only copying the file within directory but not the subfolders. The same resul

Comment: I used synchronize and the filemask is not even working as well. It is copying all files in the directory. I really prefered the put command becauseit avoids showing GUI when transfering.  The code i used is                           winscp.exe VXP_FTP_Transfer /synchronize   -criteria=none -nopreservetime -nopermissions filemask=*920024*.RDF  "C:\storage\" / /Defaults

Comment: It is all working now. I changed it to use filemask                                         put  -filemask=*920024*.RDF   "C:\RDF\*"   "/"       Thanks for your time and help

Comment: But the answer is not desirable. I still do not want subfolders to be copied along